# Selecting correct offline update file for iPad 2

Tags: itunes, ipad

I can't download from the update of my iPad 2 through iTunes. My internet connection is unstable. iTunes is giving me a hard time.

So, I googled around a bit and stumbled on this website, [iClarified](http://www.iclarified.com) which allows me to [download](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=8500) the ***.ipsw** files, with resume capability. Ok, found it.

*Please let make some noise if I shouldn't download form this website.*

Now, the issue is there are several updates for my iPad2.For the latest 5.1, I have 4 updates files to choose from,

1. 5.1.0 (iPad 2 Wi-Fi): iPad2,1_5.1_9B176_Restore.ipsw
2. 5.1.0 (iPad 2 GSM): iPad2,2_5.1_9B176_Restore.ipsw
3. 5.1.0 (iPad 2 CDMA): iPad2,3_5.1_9B176_Restore.ipsw
4. 5.1.0 (iPad 2 Unknown): iPad2,4_5.1_9B176_Restore.ipsw

Now, I am not sure, which one is for me.

My iPad is with Wifi and I am under GSM network. So, with this, either *update #1* or *update #2* is for me. As every iPad comes with wifi, so I am assuming the update #2 is correct for my phone.

Is all my deduction correct? I really want to think twice before messing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iClarified just links to IPSW files hosted by Apple (note the apple.com URLs), so it's a reasonable place to find links to download these files.

Yes, #2 sounds like the correct choice for you. (Note that if you choose the wrong IPSW, iTunes will just give you [an error message](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694) and not restore the device to it. And even if you could theoretically restore to the wrong IPSW, you can always start over and restore it again.)

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what's the *Unknown* update for?

Comment: The iPhone Wiki says [it's the second revision of the iPad 2 Wi-Fi model](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firmware#Wi-Fi_model_.28R2.29), which ["makes use of a revised CPU (A5 chip)"](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=K93aap). It's an unofficial wiki, but they usually know what they're talking about. Here's [an article found via Google](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5742/apples-ipad-24-also-uses-32nm-a5-s5l8942-soc) that has more details about it.

Comment: I brought mine a few months back, so should I go for the unknown one? How to know which version is my iPad?

Comment: It sounds like this second revision iPad 2 is just a Wi-Fi model, not a GSM + Wi-Fi model, so it isn't yours.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You have a GSM + Wi-Fi iPad 2 (according to your original question), and there is only one version of those, so IPSW #2 is the correct IPSW for you.

If you had an iPad 2 with Wi-Fi but no GSM or CDMA connectivity, you'd have to download both IPSW #1 and IPSW #4 since we wouldn't know whether you had a 1st revision or 2nd revision iPad 2 Wi-Fi.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I asked, how to know which revision of my iPad is? Is there any software to know this?

Comment: According to [this Engadget post](http://www.engadget.com/2012/05/04/rare-ipad-2-variant-32nm-processor/), you can use the desktop application [Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/) to detect this kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the model number of your iPad, you will be able to identify which iOS firmware file you need to download.

You can find model number on the iPad’s back cover as highlighted below.

[image: iPad Model Info]

Refer to the table below to identify which iOS firmware file to download based on your iPad’s model number.

For example: You need to download iPad3,4_7.0.2_11A501_Restore.ipsw file the 4th generation iPad with Wi-Fi model with model number A1458 for iOS 7.0.2 software update.

```
Model                                   Model Number    Identifier
iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi only)                    A1566         iPad5,3
iPad Air 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular                A1567         iPad5,4
iPad mini 3 (Wi-Fi only)                   A1599         iPad4,7
iPad mini 3 (Wi-Fi+Cellular only)          A1600         iPad4,8
iPad mini 3 (Wi-Fi + Cellular, China)      A1601            NA
iPad Air                                   A1474         iPad4,1
iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular                  A1475         iPad4,2
iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular (China)          A1476         iPad4,3
Retina iPad mini Wi-Fi                     A1489         iPad4,4
Retina iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular          A1490         iPad4,5
Retina iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular (China)  A1491         iPad4,6
iPad mini Wi-Fi                            A1432         iPad2,5
iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular                 A1454         iPad2,6
iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM)            A1455         iPad2,7
iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi                A1458         iPad3,4
iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular     A1459         iPad3,5
iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular(MM) A1460         iPad3,6
iPad (3rd generation) Wi-Fi                A1416         iPad3,1
iPad (3rd generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular(VZ) A1403         iPad3,2
iPad (3rd generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular     A1430         iPad3,3
iPad 2                                     A1395         iPad2,1
iPad 2 (CDMA model)                        A1397         iPad2,3
iPad 2 (GSM model)                         A1396         iPad2,2
iPad (Wi-Fi)                               A1219         iPad1,1
iPad (Wi-Fi + 3G)                          A1337         iPad1,1
```

Based on the identifier for your iPad model, you can download the appropriate iOS firmware file or iOS software update for your iPad from our download page.

[Latest iPad iOS Offline Updates](http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-ipad-ios-firmware)

Reference: [iPhonehacks](http://www.iphonehacks.com/ios-firmware-file-based-ipad-model)